# changing NaN values in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a dataframe, i do have column "Gender" and "Score"

```
Gender:'M','F','F','M','F'
Score : np.NaN,200,400,300,np.NaN
```

I need to change 'NaN' values of 'Score' column with mean of that particular gender.

Tried following code, but not working:

```
df6['Score']=df6['Score'].
fillna(df6.groupby('Gender')['Score'].transform('mean'))

df6
```

Comment: Is that NaN or string ?

Comment: NaN, it is empty value

Answer (score 3):

You can leave the result from `transform` as a dataframe and the `fillna` will work as intended.

```
df.fillna(df.groupby('Gender')[['Score']].transform('mean'))

  Gender  Score
0      M  300.0
1      F  200.0
2      F  400.0
3      M  300.0
4      F  300.0
```

Comment: i want empty values of 'Score' column to be replaced by mean of that particular gender. Rest value of 'Score' should be as it is.

Comment: Yes, I understood.  Is that not what I've shown?  What is the mean of `M`?  it is `300`.  Mean of `F` is also `300`.

Comment: Dataframe do have another columns as well, such as First Name, Last Name, Pre Score. I want values to be changed specifically in 'Score' column. Using above code it is not happening

Comment: I've fixed it such that it only updates the `Score` column

Comment: Thanks for the fix, still it is not updating dataframe, i am not sure why. If you refer my code, it is same as you have suggested.